# Using Userform Commandbutton Caption as Public Variable

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform with several commandbuttons on it with unique captions on each button.  I intend to use the caption as a variable within code in a module.

The 1st button (commandbutton13) clicked works fine.  But when I click the 2nd button (commandbutton14), it still maintains the caption from the 1st button (commandbutton13) as the variable.

```
Private Sub CommandButton13_Click() 'PRIC Button userform

HoldType = UF_Dashboard.CommandButton13.Caption   'caption is PRIC
HoldText = UF_Dashboard.TextBox5.Value
sCell = UF_Dashboard.TextBox4.Value

'Check for sales order and hold text
If TextBox4.Text = "" Or TextBox5.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox ("You must enter a Sales Order and Hold Text to continue.")
    Exit Sub
End If

Hold

End Sub



Private Sub CommandButton14_Click() 'CUST Button on userform

HoldType = UF_Dashboard.CommandButton14.Caption    'caption is CUST
HoldText = UF_Dashboard.TextBox5.Value
sCell = UF_Dashboard.TextBox4.Value

'Check for sales order and hold text
If TextBox4.Text = "" Or TextBox5.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox ("You must enter a Sales Order and Hold Text to continue.")
    Exit Sub
End If

Hold

End Sub
```

Within the module I have the following:

```
Public HoldType as String
```

I need help understanding why HoldType is showing as PRIC after clicking commandbutton14.  Even in developer mode I cannot select the line so I assume it's locking in on the 1st definition of HoldType in commandbutton13 code.

Comment: As a Public variable within the Module it will retain its value even after the code execution is complete. So when you click the command button it should start with the previous value and then overwrite that with the new value.

Comment: Also worth Watching the HoldType variable as you step through the code (F8). If you right-click on the HoldType where you have declared it at the top and select the Watch option.

Comment: What happens in `Hold` ?

Comment: Best guess is that something happens in code where you have hard coded either `CommandButton13` or 'PRIC'.  What happens if you do not press `CommandButton13` but press `CommandButton14` only.  Does it still show 'PRIC'?

Comment: Hi Gareth.  Yep if Click `CommandButton13` it properly sets HoldType to PRIC.  But then when i click `CommandButton14` it doesn't change to CUST, it stays as PRIC.  Even when I try to step through the code it will not let me choose that line as a next statement and it does not execute it.  It's almost like the definition in the previous sub is taking precedence.

Comment: Hi Tim.  Hold sub uses the HoldType to run some scripts in SAP.  I am effectively pasting the HoldType into a field in SAP and I want that to be based on whatever button gets pushed.

Comment: Is this the complete code - nothing left out?  I don't see anything to explain what you're seeing.

Comment: Perhaps a run-time error occurs after clicking command button 13, which is why you can't step into the code when clicking command button 14. Go to Tools, Options, General tab and make sure "Break in Class Module" is selected in the "Error Trapping" group, then try clicking the buttons again.